# making a audio file sound in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to play a .ogg file which i also converted into a .mp3 file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


<body onclick = "playSound('file:///C:/Users/Rehaan/Downloads/myfirstrecording%20(3).ogg');">

  <p id = "sound">
  </p>
  Click here to play the sound!
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the java script file,

```
function playSound( url ){   
  document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML="<embed src='"+url+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";
}
```

Comment: That seems not to be working

Comment: Is this a problem with the url or is it a problem with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the HTML5 audio tag.

```
      <audio id="audio_samples" src="mymp3audiofile.mp3" controls></audio>
```

The audio tag supports mp3, ogg, and wav audio files.

Also, here are Javascript audio control functions that you may find useful:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio_samples");
                  
                  
        function playAudio() {
            audio.play();    
        }

        function pauseAudio() {
            audio.pause();    
        }
        
        function restartAudio() {
            audio.load(); 
            audio.play();
        }
        
        function louder() {
            audio.volume += 0.1;
        }
        
        function softer() {
            audio.volume -= 0.1;
        }
      </script>
      
      <button onclick="playAudio()">Play</button>
      <button onclick="pauseAudio()">Pause</button>
      <button onclick="restartAudio()">Restart</button>
      <button onclick="louder()">Louder</button>
      <button onclick="softer()">Softer</button>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 Tag which is `<audio>`. It can play .mp3, .ogg, .wav format.
This is an example that I got from w3schools.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```